# How to pass relaystate parameter from salesforce community to Azure

Tags: customer-community, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I am enabling SAML2.0 Authentication for Salesforce community users. During Authentication I want to pass Relay state parameter dynamically to Azure(IDP) so that users can navigate to a different community page after authentication.

I am unable to find any Salesforce documentation how to achieve this. Please help

Comment: SF will do it for you in some scenarios..and in other cases you have to write code to do it yourself. Please revise your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `RelayState` as a url parameter on your login page so that it points to the page you want users to navigate to on a successful login.

See [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331033&type=1&mode=1) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the response the link that you provided  state details how to add relay state at the IDP end. I want to pass relay state from the service provider.